# (errno: 121) en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Problemas al compilar:

> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
>
> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
>
> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
>
> Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
>
> Database changed
>
> Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
>
> Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
>
> Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
>
> ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'dba1_s4a.pelicula' (errno:
>   121) ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'dba1_s4a.ejemplar'
>   (errno: 121) Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
>
> ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'dba1_s4a.renta' (errno: 121)
>   ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'dba1_s4a.reparto' (errno: 121)
>   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
>
> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
>
> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Código de MySQL:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema dba1_s4a
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema dba1_s4a
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `dba1_s4a` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 ;
USE `dba1_s4a` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `dba1_s4a`.`actor`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dba1_s4a`.`actor` (
`actor` INT(3) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
`nombre` VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
`nacionalidad` VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
PRIMARY KEY (`actor`) COMMENT '')
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `dba1_s4a`.`director`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dba1_s4a`.`director` (
`director` INT(3) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
`nombre` VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
`nacionalidad` VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
PRIMARY KEY (`director`) COMMENT '')
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `dba1_s4a`.`genero`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dba1_s4a`.`genero` (
`genero` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
`nombre` VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT '',
PRIMARY KEY (`genero`) COMMENT '')
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `dba1_s4a`.`pelicula`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dba1_s4a`.`pelicula` (
`pelicula` INT(3) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
`titulo` VARCHAR(40) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
`nacionalidad` VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
`fecha` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
`sinopsis` MEDIUMTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
`director` INT(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
`genero` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
PRIMARY KEY (`pelicula`) COMMENT '',
INDEX `dirige` (`director` ASC) COMMENT '',
INDEX `genero1_idx` (`genero` ASC) COMMENT '',
CONSTRAINT `dirige`
FOREIGN KEY (`director`)
REFERENCES `dba1_s4a`.`director` (`director`),
CONSTRAINT `genero1`
FOREIGN KEY (`genero`)
REFERENCES `dba1_s4a`.`genero` (`genero`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `dba1_s4a`.`ejemplar`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dba1_s4a`.`ejemplar` (
`noejemplar` INT(4) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
`estado` VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
`pelicula` INT(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
PRIMARY KEY (`noejemplar`) COMMENT '',
INDEX `dispone` (`pelicula` ASC) COMMENT '',
CONSTRAINT `dispone`
FOREIGN KEY (`pelicula`)
REFERENCES `dba1_s4a`.`pelicula` (`pelicula`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `dba1_s4a`.`socio`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dba1_s4a`.`socio` (
`nosocio` INT(4) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
`nombre` VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
`direccion` VARCHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
`telefono` VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
PRIMARY KEY (`nosocio`) COMMENT '')
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `dba1_s4a`.`renta`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dba1_s4a`.`renta` (
`noejemplar` INT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '',
`nosocio` INT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '',
`frenta` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
`fdev` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
`precio` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
PRIMARY KEY (`noejemplar`, `nosocio`) COMMENT '',
INDEX `alquila` (`nosocio` ASC) COMMENT '',
CONSTRAINT `alquila`
FOREIGN KEY (`nosocio`)
REFERENCES `dba1_s4a`.`socio` (`nosocio`),
CONSTRAINT `es_alquilado`
FOREIGN KEY (`noejemplar`)
REFERENCES `dba1_s4a`.`ejemplar` (`noejemplar`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `dba1_s4a`.`reparto`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dba1_s4a`.`reparto` (
`pelicula` INT(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '',
`actor` INT(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '',
`papel` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
PRIMARY KEY (`pelicula`, `actor`) COMMENT '',
INDEX `actua` (`actor` ASC) COMMENT '',
CONSTRAINT `actua`
FOREIGN KEY (`actor`)
REFERENCES `dba1_s4a`.`actor` (`actor`),
CONSTRAINT `actuan`
FOREIGN KEY (`pelicula`)
REFERENCES `dba1_s4a`.`pelicula` (`pelicula`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Answer (score 1):

¿Qué versión de MySQL utiliza?. No puedo reproducir el problema en MySQL 5.7.

Ejecuté el script indicado en la pregunta con el siguiente resultado:

```sql
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.11    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> \. script.sql
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0,00 sec)

Database changed
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,01 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,01 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> SHOW TABLES;
+--------------------+
| Tables_in_dba1_s4a |
+--------------------+
| actor              |
| director           |
| ejemplar           |
| genero             |
| pelicula           |
| renta              |
| reparto            |
| socio              |
+--------------------+
8 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

Comment: Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 37
Server version: 5.5.53-0+deb8u1 (Debian)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.
 ya quedo muchas gracias por su respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Tal como @wchiquito, no puedo reproducir tu error. De modo que puede que sea un problema que solo se manifiesta en tu versión específica de MySQL, o en tu configuración específica.

Sin embargo, al examinar más cuidadosamente las tablas que te dieron los errores, sospecho que se trata de un conflicto entre los nombres de los índices y los nombres de las claves foráneas.

Por ejemplo, en la tabla `pelicula`, tienes un índice y una clave foránea que ambos los defines con el nombre `dirige`. Noto conflictos similares con las otras tablas `ejemplar`, `renta` y `reparto`.

Te sugiero que cambies los nombres para evitar estos conflictos. Por ejemplo, intenta cambiar los 2 `dirige` a `dirige_idx` y `dirige_fk` respectivamente. Luego haz lo mismo con las demás tablas para corregir los demás conflictos en los nombres. Puede que eso solucione tu problema.

Comment: Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 37
Server version: 5.5.53-0+deb8u1 (Debian)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Comment: @Luis: no entiendo tu comentario.